# XSD restriction with mathematical constants

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

My question is quite straight-forward. With XSD, is it possible to restrict a value with mathematical constants like PI. For example, when you want a radian value between 0 and PI.

If not, is there an elegant and simple way to do it ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `simpleType` with the range you want:

```
<xs:simpleType name="radianType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="3.14159265358979323846"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And reuse it in elements and attributes:

```
<xs:element name="horizon" type="radianType"/>
```